# How to remove match comment tag from in html use preg_replace

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

i've problem to remove this tag `<!-- comment -->`look too the empty space in that tag. how to remove it and also change it to empty character not space use `preg_replace()`

solved

just use this syntax:

`$content = "hello <!--- comment --> world";`

`$html = preg_replace('/<!-- comment -->/i','',$content);`

Output

`hello world`

Answer (score 2):

It's dangerous to use preg_replace or any other text-tool to manipulate HTML! The answers so far are horrible, and can cause HTML to break in several ways. Use DOM for HTML, DOMDocument can loadHTML() and then you can simply remove comment nodes, or those comments that startwith/are 'pagebreak'.

Comment: thanks, horrible like what ? could you to explain a little bit about that. thanks

Comment: They break legal HTML like ```<p>text <!-- old: <!-- comment --> important</p>```

Answer (score 0):

dont use preg_replace(), you can simply do:

```
 $html = str_replace("<!-- pagebreak -->", "<!--pagebreak-->", $html);
```

Comment: what if comment is something different?

Comment: thanks buddy. currently that i need have to use `preg_replace()` method.